# How to calculate savings total in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

**UPD

Solved:**

```
function wc_discount_total_30() {

    global $woocommerce;

    $discount_total = 0;

    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) {

   $_product = $values['data'];

        if ( $_product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $regular_price = $_product->get_regular_price();
        $sale_price = $_product->get_sale_price();
        $discount = ($regular_price - $sale_price) * $values['quantity'];
        $discount_total += $discount;
        }

    }    

if ( $woocommerce->cart->subtotal + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total > $woocommerce->cart->total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total || $discount_total >0 ) {

    echo '<tr class="cart-discount">
    <th>'. __( 'Saved:', 'woocommerce' ) .'</th>
    <td data-title=" '. __( 'Saved', 'woocommerce' ) .' ">' 
    . wc_price( $woocommerce->cart->subtotal - $woocommerce->cart->total + $woocommerce->cart->shipping_total + $discount_total ) .'</td>
    </tr>';
}    

}

// Hook our values to the Basket and Checkout pages

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_order_total', 'wc_discount_total_30', 99);
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', 'wc_discount_total_30', 99);
```

### --------------------------------------------------------------------

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I want to calculate and display «Total Savings» in Cart and Checkout page (Woocommerce). I've tried to use this code, but it only works if I have at least one discounted item in my cart:

```
function wc_discount_total_30() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $discount_total = 0;
    foreach ( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values) {
        $_product = $values['data'];
        if ( $_product->is_on_sale() ) {
            $regular_price = $_product->get_regular_price();
            $sale_price = $_product->get_sale_price();
            $discount = ($regular_price - $sale_price) * $values['quantity'];
            $discount_total += $discount;
        }
    }
    if ( $discount_total > 0 ) {
        echo '<tr class="cart-discount">
        <th>'. __( 'Saved', 'tsavedis' ) .'</th>
        <td data-title=" '. __( 'Saved', 'tsavedis' ) .' ">'
        . wc_price( $discount_total + $woocommerce->cart->discount_cart ) .'</td>
        </tr>';
    }
}

// Hook our values to the Basket and Checkout pages
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_totals_after_order_total', 'wc_discount_total_30', 99);
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_after_order_total', 'wc_discount_total_30', 99);
```

But I need to calculate the discount amount considering the coupon and the amount of items in the cart (whether there are discounted items in the cart or not). Here is my code for displaying discount based on the number of items in shopping cart:

```
function woo_discount_total(WC_Cart $cart) {

    $woo_count_item = $cart->get_cart_contents_count(); // Number of items in the shopping cart

    if($woo_count_item >= 3 && $woo_count_item <= 4) {

        $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.10; // 0.10 — 10%
        $cart->add_fee("10% discount for 3-4 items in the shopping cart", -$discount);

    } elseif($woo_count_item >= 5 && $woo_count_item <= 100) {

        $discount = $cart->subtotal * 0.20; // 0.20 — 20%
        $cart->add_fee("20% discount for 5 and more items in the shopping cart", -$discount);

    }

}

add_action("woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees" , "woo_discount_total");
```

What I want to display:

Cart Subtotal: $1000
Coupon: -$50
10% discount for 3 items in Cart: -$100
Order Total: $850
**Saved: $150**

I think the easiest way to do that is to subtract «order total» from «cart subtotal». Is there any way to do this?